# Email/ID duplicate check in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, spring

In Sign up form, I wanna make Duplication check.
When is duplicated, A message is shown below the input box.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-2 control-label"><strong>Email</strong></label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
     <input type="email" class="form-control" name="usr_Email" 
            ng-model="usrEmail" ng-keyup="checkDuplicate()">
     <span class="help-block" 
           ng-show="signupForm.$submitted || signupForm.usr_Email.$touched">
        <div ng-show="?????" class="text-danger">is duplicated!</div>
     </span>
     </div>
</div>
```

to check duplicate, I got counting number from server

```
$scope.user.usrEmail = $scope.usrEmail;         
var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: './api/v1/public/checkDuplication',
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: { 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        },
        data: angular.toJson($scope.user)
    };

$http(req).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
    $log.debug($filter('json')(data));
    if(data.number == 0){
        ???????
    }
    else{
        ???????????????
    }
```

I'm very confused about what I should write in '???'

In advance, thanks!

Comment: `I'm very confused about what I should write in '???'` what do you mean?

Comment: I mean, I don't know how to code in the '???'.

Comment: check my answer

Comment: have you got the answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Controller:**

```
if(data.number == 0){
    //If email id is duplicate, then show the message in UI
      $scope.isDuplicate = true;    
} else{
   //If email id is not duplicate, then hide the message in UI
     $scope.isDuplicate = false;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-show="isDuplicate" class="text-danger">is duplicated!</div>
```

I have used `isDuplicate` scope variable to show the message.